# React checkbox input for replacement to radio buttons

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a checkbox for a true/false value. The idea is to render a checkbox that when checked, changes state to '1', when unchecked, changes the state to '0'. Right now here is my components state:

```
this.state = {
    attrValue: ''
};
```

The JSX checkbox:

```
<div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.attrValue === '1'}
                        value={this.state.attrValue}
                        onChange={this._handleInputChange}
                        name="attrValue"
                    />
                </div>
```

The on change handler:

```
_handleInputChange(e) {
    const element = e.target;
    const stateObject = {};

    stateObject[element.name] = element.value;
    this.setState(stateObject);
}
```

As of now, clicking the checkbox does not modify the state. Im not entirely sure if this is even possible. With radio buttons I would just render a true and false radio button with values set to 1 and 0. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not too far off in your code.

Take a look at this fiddle I created. Note that I made the initial state a simpler boolean rather than an empty string, and I set the state to the value of the checkbox on its `onChange`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tp3k4wpL/

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      attrValue: false
    };
    this._handleInputChange = this._handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }
  _handleInputChange(e) {
      const element = e.target;
      this.setState({attrValue: element.checked});
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.attrValue}
            onChange={this._handleInputChange}
            name="attrValue"
        />
        {`State of checkbox: ${this.state.attrValue}`}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
React.render(<Foo />, document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)! The jsfiddle helped a lot

Comment: No problem! You were close, you probably just needed a second set of eyes